# beamer reference manual

Tags: beamer

The `beamer` user manual is undoubtedly a work of love, but sometimes I'd like to have at hand some more to the point reference material.

Could you please point me to a short manual, possibly with the commands sorted alphabetically and with a description of all the optional arguments they take?

Tx in advance.

Answer (score 6):

A subset of commands (relevant for the appearance of the slides) is nicely presented in

http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: good to know! (+1)

Comment: Thank you, a good answer (upvoted) though not exactly what I've asked for...